# Dictionaries and Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

I have this code:

```
class weapon():
    def __init__(self, Name, Type, Description):
        self.Name=Name
        self.Type=Type
        self.Description=Description

WEAPONS = { "starterSword":weapon("Starter Sword", "Sword", "A short, stunt steel sword."),
        "basicSword":weapon("Basic Sword", "Sword", "A basic steel sword.")
        }
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
for item in WEAPONS:
    print(self.Name)
```

How would I go about doing it in Python 3?

Comment: too easy to be an issue ...

Comment: It looks like you're just starting out with Python. The usual (PEP8) naming convention is to use capitalized Class names and lowercase (snake case) argument names. In this case: `class Weapon(object): def __init__(self, name, type, description)`

Comment: I'm using Type instead of type because type is a python function, and I want to use it as a variable. I thought that, instead of having one variable with a capital letter, I should be consistent throughout.

Comment: As an aside, you should really stick to the PEP8 style guide. So, use snake_case for variable/attribute/parameter names, UpperCase for class names.

Comment: Seems like a weird duplicate. I mean this question is about Python, not swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate over the [values](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
for item in WEAPONS.values():
    print(item.Name)
```

Comment: For python2 you should mention itervalues() instead.

Comment: That's correct but I assumed python-3.x because the question contained a `print` with `()`. However it's only an optimization to use `itervalues` on 2.x anyway - `values()` will also work correctly there (just a bit slower and more memory expensive).

Comment: Correct, that slowness and memory was the reason for my last sentence in my now deleted answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It would appear that OP is very new to Python. I very much doubt he cares about optimizing his code. If he does, well you know what they say about premature optimization.

Comment: @xyres I think you should care about "good answers" rather than "just good enough answers", and that's my point here, which people are missing.

Comment: @xyres I've been using Python for 2 years now. I'm just terrible with it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ But the question asks about Python 3 specifically (title + print with parenthesis) and then it's not just good enough. It's the recommended (best) way to iterate over the values in Python 3. And I actually upvoted your comment that recommends `itervalues` for python-2.x which complements the answer quite nicely. :)

Comment: Sometimes answering questions in this tag is fun.., and other times it's total garbage. That question on printing variables based on user input, for instance. What a mockery.

Answer (score 1):

As @MSeifert said. Anyway, iterating over a dictionary gives you the key and value for every item. So this works, too:

```
for key, value in WEAPONS.items():
    print(value.Name)
```

By the way: Why are you using a dictionary? Since each weapon holds its own name.

Comment: "_So this works, too:_" it doesn't ...

Comment: I'm using a dictionary so that I can go through each weapon and check the value of all the variables. I want to have an inventory system that scans through all the weapons and finds which weapons has Equipped="True". That is the one that it will display.

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @SquidyEmerald right, but why not just a `list` for example? Or use the actual `Name` attribute of your weapon object as the key?

Answer (score 1):

Best when you write the methods inside the class (OOP) and call them without having to write lots of code e.g.

```
class weapon():
    def __init__(self, Name, Type, Description):
        self.Name=Name
        self.Type=Type
        self.Description=Description
    def printDetails(self):
        print (self.Name)

WEAPONS = { "starterSword":weapon("Starter Sword", "Sword", "A short, stunt steel sword.").printDetails(),
        "basicSword":weapon("Basic Sword", "Sword", "A basic steel sword.").printDetails()
        }
```

Will give you the desired output.